# Adding scrolling items dynamically to specific places on a JscrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

The short version of the question:   I have a JScrollPane with a large number of items being scrolled.  At certain times I'd like to add some items to the JScrollPane and have them appear NOT at the end of the list, but after (for example) the 17th item.

Normally if the code in question is within the JScrollPane derived class, I just say this.add();  But I believe this goes to the end of the list.

Rationales:   Case 1: The underlying data I'm scrolling is an ordered list of items but additions are allowed at any point of the list.  When I add things to the middle of the list, I want to avoid loading the whole list again into the JScrollPane.

Case 2: I'm simulating a scrolling list with expanding subcategories.  So if the user picks an item that has expanding subcategories, my Action code recognizes this case, looks into program data to find the subcategories, and then adds them to the JScrollPane beneath the chosen category.  Don't worry about it, but there will also be some visual indication that it is a subcategory, supplied by my action code.

I can code all of this.  All I am hoping to learn is how to add something to a JScrollPane without it being added to the end of the list.

Comment: 1- You shouldn't be calling `JScrollPane#add`; 2- The answer depends on what this "component" is

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what this component is that you are adding your items to. If you are using a `JList`, you could use something like [`DefaultListModel#add(int, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add(int,%20E)) to add an item to a specific location.

If you're using something based on a `JComponent` (like a `JPanel`), you can use [`JComponent#add(Component, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20int)) to specify the location that the component should be added, this assumes that the location exists (ie you can't add a component to position 100 if the container only contains a single component).

The following example generates a random number, determines the location that the number should be inserted in order to maintain a ordered list and inserts a component at that point.  It will also attempt to scroll the `JScrollPane` to make the item visible

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test10();
    }

    public Test10() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel numbers;
        private List<Integer> values;

        public TestPane() {
            values = new ArrayList<>(25);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            numbers = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            add(new JScrollPane(numbers));

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int next = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    int insertion = Collections.binarySearch(values, next);
                    if (insertion < 0) {
                        insertion = (Math.abs(insertion)) - 1;
                    }
                    values.add(insertion, next);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(next));
                    numbers.add(label, insertion);
                    numbers.revalidate();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Point p = label.getLocation();
                            JViewport vp = (JViewport) numbers.getParent();
                            JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) vp.getParent();
                            vp.setViewPosition(p);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great but I have a comment and a further request.  This gives me the answer to my first scenario (I didn't know about the optional position parameter in the add method) but I realize my second scenario isn't as easy as I thought.

Comment: My previous comment got cut off.  To solve the second scenario, an object that is a member of a JList wants to add another member to the JList, immediately after itself.  It seems the child object needs to find out what its 'index' is in the JList and then invoke the JList's add function with the desired object and the index immediately after its own.  How does a child object find its index?

Comment: If her using a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), you can use the indexOf method